# I want to get distinct character from a string.The following program gives the result but followed by an exception as well.What is the mistake?

Tags: java, string

I want to get distinct character from a string.The following program gives the result but followed by an exception as well.What is the mistake?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stringchar {

    public static void count(String s)
    {
        String s1;
        while(s!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
            s1=""+s.charAt(0);
            s=s.replace(s1,"");
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sc.nextLine();
        count(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: What error does it give you? That's very important

Comment: I dont get what your code is supposed to do. Why can't you just loop over the chars of the string, instead of doing this strange thing to only work on char(0)?!

Comment: You'll get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because `s` is never `null`, but rather becomes `""`.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop you have a termination condition that can never be satisfied and so you keep replacing characters with `""` until you have an empty string which causes `s.charAt(0)` to throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You get an array out of bounds exception because you have a while loop. You should try and do this:

```
    String s1;
    if(s!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
        s1=""+s.charAt(0);
        s=s.replace(s1,"");
    }
```

Using `while` will keep going over the code again and again. At some point you replace all the characters of the string and thus get an array out of bounds exception. I think you wanted the `if` statement, not the while.